# Debugging production JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Please see the code below:

```
function TestAjax
{
   //AJAX asynchronous call 1
   //AJAX asynchronous call 2
   //AJAX asynchronous call 3
   //AJAX asynchronous call n
}
```

There are n AJAX calls to the server (up to about 50).  On the production server some of the AJAX calls are returning errors: "internal server error".  My research tells me that it is a server side error.  The website runs perfectly on my development PC and on the test server.  The AJAX calls are generated using JQuery and the server side code is: ASP.NET (VB.NET).

What is the best way of debugging on the production server? Is it just a matter of attaching Visual Studio to the W3WP process?

Comment: Check the production logs (you should be logging exceptions) - you can always point your local dev to the production servers and step thru the code as well.

Comment: Is it Cross-origin policy? Your webservice needs to be on the same server as web application unless you do something like jsonp.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it just a matter of attaching Visual Studio to the W3WP process?

While this remains a last chance possibility, you might also consider introducing logging in your server side endpoints. You know, things like global exception handlers that will log the error to a centralized source like a file or the Event Log of your server. Those sources are always the first thing you should consider looking at when confronted with similar situation.

Comment: Thanks.  I use JavaScript alerts. Sometimes it says: "error" and others: "internal server error". What is the difference?

Comment: Pretty hard to say without knowing more details about what possible client side code you might have written and about what server side code you might have written. All you have shown in your question is some javascript function containing commented lines of code saying `AJAX asynchronous call 1` through `n` which pretty much means nothing. Also bear in mind that using `alerts` for debugging javascript code is not probably the best means.

Comment: Use StackExchange.Exceptional https://github.com/NickCraver/StackExchange.Exceptional to log global exceptions or use Serilog http://serilog.net/ and define your own logging details where you want.